# Autofac - passing instance to constructor parameter via xml configuration

Tags: xml, dependency-injection, ioc-container, autofac

I've an implementation which takes MemoryCache as a constructor parameter.

My xml configuration:

```
 <autofac defaultAssembly="Test.Caching">
    <component name="memoryCache"
        type="System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache, System.Runtime.Caching">
        <parameters>
           <parameter name="name" value="TestCache"/>
        </parameters>
    </component>

    <component type="My.Caching.TaskCache, Test.Caching" service="Test.Caching.ITaskCache" >
        <parameters>
          <parameter name="cache" value="testCache" />
        </parameters>
    </component>
 </autofac>
```

I'm using Autofac.Configuration and registering xml via:

```
builder.RegisterModule(new ConfigurationSettingsReader("autofac", "<configPath>"));
```

I get following error:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: The type 'System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache, System.Runtime.Caching' could not be found. It may re
quire assembly qualification, e.g. "MyType, MyAssembly".
   at Autofac.Configuration.ConfigurationRegistrar.LoadType(String typeName, Assembly defaultAssembly)
   at Autofac.Configuration.ConfigurationRegistrar.RegisterConfiguredComponents(ContainerBuilder builder, SectionHandler configurationSection)
   at Autofac.Configuration.ConfigurationRegistrar.RegisterConfigurationSection(ContainerBuilder builder, SectionHandler configurationSection)
   at Autofac.Configuration.Core.ConfigurationModule.Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
   at Autofac.Module.Configure(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry)
   at Autofac.ContainerBuilder.Build(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, Boolean excludeDefaultModules)
   at Autofac.ContainerBuilder.Build(ContainerBuildOptions options)
```

I've referenced - System.Runtime.Caching in the project.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need an interface for your declaration:

```
<component name="memoryCache"
type="System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache, System.Runtime.Caching"
service="your.interface.IMemoryCache, your.interface"
```